# SQL - Loop through a list and add to a variable using sql select statements

Tags: sql, loops

I have data loaded in a table called Trades. Now I need to query this table, find elements that satisfy a particular condition and produce the trade value amount. 
Here is the requirement

```
TradeAmt = 0
Loop for all Trades 
{IF TradeId is 35 
  If type = 'I'
    ADD (TradeAmt =TradeAmt + col_TradeAmt )
else 
    ADD (TradeAmt = TradeAmt + col_TradeAmtOverlap )
END-IF}
Return TradeAmt
```

Data:
Row1: tradeid=35, type=I, col_TradeAmt=10, col_TradeAmtOverlap=20

Row2: tradeid=35, type=S, col_TradeAmt=30, col_TradeAmtOverlap=40

Output: TradeAmt=50

How can i write this using SQL statements.

Comment: which sql database? also helpful if you post sample data and expected output. your solution may be different to what we can understand from OP

Comment: Can there be multiple trades with id=35?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It's not clear what you want. This is a good guide to 'How to Ask Question'. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you think you "need" to loop? Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve]. You need to read an intro to SQL. What references were you told to use?

Comment: In sql you can loop through data using a cursor.  But generally Sql achieves greater speed by doing things in batchs.  You don't want to loop though this data you want to get a sql command that does this in a single command batch of data.

Comment: @chetan yes there will be many trades with id 35

Answer (score 1):

Well, in SQL you don't really loop over a sequence.
You write a statement that describes what you want to get from the set of data (e.g. the Trades table).

In your case, you want to accumulate all the elements in some way and provide that accumulation as a result, you can do that by using an aggregate function like SUM.

Something along these lines probably could work. Note that I'm nesting two queries here, the inner one to decide which column to treat as the "Amount" to accumulate depending on the Type of the trade and also to filter only the trade with Id 35, and the outer query performs the sum aggregate of all amounts:

```
SELECT SUM("Amount") FROM
(SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN Type = 'I' THEN col_TradeAmt
  ELSE col_TradeAmtOverlap
END "Amount"
FROM Trades
WHERE TradeId = 35) "TradeAmt";
```

Comment: Or more simply `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'I' THEN col_TradeAmt ELSE col_TradeAmtOverlap END) FROM Trades WHERE TradeId = 35`